# Reload an iframe without flickering/flash (in Javascript)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to ask if anyone has a simple solution that will allow me to reload/refresh an iframe but without the flickering/flash when the page reloads, it that possible ? 
Maybe to animate a blur-out and then a blur-in instead of the flickering/flash? I don't know any input would be helpful,

Thanks.

Here is how I reload the iframe now

```
document.getElementById("FrameID").contentDocument.location.reload(true);
```

Thanks for the help.

Comment: No. I don't think that is possible. It needs to reload the page so will always have a bit of flickering.

Comment: It's called FOUC and it's not easily fixed.  Where it's normally CSS related, in this case it's iFrame source related.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**Easiest approach:**

1. Create a new iframe outside of DOM or in a hidden element.
2. Load the page inside the hidden frame
3. Once the load even fires within the hidden frame, just swap them around!

**Swapping**

To actually swap them, just have them next to each other and toggle the `display: none / block` css of each one.

Comment: cool!! :)  But how do you swap them around ? (I never seen that sounds super cool)

Comment: I've added an example

Comment: @compcobalt A number of ways I suppose, but the easiest might just be to place the new one immediately after the one you're displaying in the DOM then hide the old one and show the new one. How immediate that'll be I'm not sure.

Comment: Just like @Thor84no says, having them one next to each other and simply showing / hiding will be easiest and fastest.

Comment: Thank you. Lifesaver in my situation http://codecorner.galanter.net/2016/05/05/flicker-free-iframe-refresh/

Comment: Very. Tricky. I'm impressed.

Comment: Have successfully implemented mr. Galanters solution, but is there way to skip timeout on first iframe load? Have frame which should be refreshed every 5 secs, but displayed immediatelly on page load...

Answer (score 2):

What you can try is to place the `iframe` inside a container `div`:

```
<div id="iframe-container">
    <iframe src="..."></iframe>
</div>
```

Then in your JavaScript create a second `iframe`, place it behind if the first `iframe` and then hide the first one:

```
var container = document.getElementById('iframe-container');

var iframe2 = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe2.src = 'http://new.url.com';
iframe2.style.visibility = 'hidden';
container.appendChild(iframe2);

container.removeChild(container.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0]);
iframe2.style.visibility = 'visible';
```

Hope this works, I haven't tested it. You will also need to play around with your CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Really there is no way to avoid the flicker, as that is the page refreshing and rendering the new content.

You could hide the iframe on a refresh.  And in the iframe, when the DOM is ready, call some parent function via parent.functionName() that will then make the iframe visible.